# Firestore bundler builder not deploying correctly

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-extensions

when installing the extension, firebase deployed the it, but I'm getting this error:

> Build failed: lib/index.js does not exist; Error ID: bc73f5cd

The package JSON seems to have a reference to "main": "lib/index.js", but it doesn't exist I guess it should be src/index.

how can I make this extension to work?

Answer (score 2):

An issue for this is also tracked on the official Github repository for this Extension [here](https://github.com/firebase/firestore-bundle-builder).

An update will be required to update the published version of the Extension as the compiled files are not building as expected.

In the meantime, developers could manually install this extension through the Firebase Cli.

```
git clone git@github.com:firebase/firestore-bundle-builder.git

npm install

firebase ext:install firebase/firestore-bundle-builder --project={project_Id}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to deploy functions, and they are not built, so the compiler is throwing error. Go to functions and build functions so they can be deployed. Or deploy everything except Firebase functions.

Comment: I'm installing it from firebase marketplace it should be a matter of just "click and go"

Comment: @pedrommuller You are probably getting source code you need to compile. The thing is you are lack of file inside `functions/lib/index.js` Firebase is deploying that file to firebase functions. Just go to functions folder and run `npm run build` that's it.

Comment: I can't run NPM run build if I'm installing the extension directly from firebase marketplace, it's just a button that says install in console, it's supposed to do the build from me but apparently it doens't

Comment: @pedrommuller I don't know, I didn't install any extensions yet. Exp lice it in your question title or inside of it.

Comment: @pedrommuller Or no, you got it, in post I just miss that.